# Use Angular 1.x (AngularJS) service inside Angular 2+ Service

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-upgrade

Is it possible to use Angular 1.x service inside Angular 2+ service? I am getting the following error when doing so:

> Trying to get the AngularJS injector before it being set.

However, it works if I use Angular 1 service inside Angular 2 component (instead of service).

**App.Module.ts**:

```
function getA1Service(i:any) { return i.get('a1Service') }

@NgModule({
     declarations: [...],
     imports: [...],
     entryComponents: [...],
     providers: [...,
          A2Service,
          { provide: 'a1Service', useFactory: getA1Service, deps: '$injector']},
     ],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { 
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule)  {
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
  }

}
```

**A2Service.ts**:

```
export class A2Service {

    constructor(private http:HttpClient, @Inject('a1Service') private a1Service) {}

    getData() : Observable<data> {
    return this.http.get<data>(...);
    }
}
```

**Main.ts**:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
  const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
  upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['app']);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```